# How to print Client Report Definition file (.rdlc) on A4 size in C#?

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

I am trying to print a report using C# Report Viewer Control.

*By the way, I bumped into a problem.*

I wanted my `.rdlc` file to be printed on A4 size. so I changed `.rdlc` file size with A4 size 210X297(mm) in the *VS2010 designer*. But the report viewer object that uses this `.rdlc` file automatically sets the margins on the paper. So the total size of the paper that will be printed was over A4 size.

I can't estimate the size of the margin. 
Is there any way to estimate or control the size of the margin?

I have been searching for the last some days...
I need help. please give me a hand.

My platform is `VS2010 / .Net 4.0 / C#`

---

Thanks tezzo for your help. I appriciate it.
My problem was which I didn't know the fact that Report > Report properties > Page setup exists.
I could resolve my problem by your advice.
But I had what makes me confused. so I leave some aditional pictures. 
I hope it is helpful to another person who encounters such a problem.

1. You have to click the point that the picture 1 expresses by the check sign. If you click the point that the picture 2 expresses by the check sign, you can not see such a properties window that have a Margins and a PageSize Property, which makes me confused.

When you reach here, you can follow tezzo's advice. then you can print rdlc file on A4 size.

I am first to write here. so I can't add any picture on it. 
I link pictures.

< picture 1>

[image]

< picture 2 >

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set paper size and margins in *Report > Report properties > Page setup*.

I usually use this settings:

- paper size: A4
- size: 21 x 29,7 (landscape: 29,7 x 21)
- left/right margin: 1,3cm
- bottom/top margins: 1,5cm

So the maximum width of report will be:

- 21 - (1,3*2) = 18,4cm
- 29,7 - (1,3*2) = 27,1cm (landscape)

Comment: Could you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633350/how-to-show-report-data-in-center-of-rdlc-report